# Can I use res.send() node.js method inside the loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am beginner in node.js. I have created node server and write simple program using express, sending response using res.send() method. If a user visit the route like "/repeat/hello/5" should print hello 5 times and there are spaces between the word. Example :
hello hello hello hello hello

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var animalsData = {
    "dog" : "Bow Bow",
    "cat" : "Meow",
    "pig" : "Oink",
    "horse" : "Hiha",
    "lion" : "Roar"
}

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("Hi there! Welcome to my asssingment.");
});

app.get("/speak/:animal", function(req, res){
    var name = req.params.animal;

    if(animalsData[name]){
        res.send("The " +name+ " says '" +animalsData[name]+ "'.");
    } else
        res.send("I don't know what " +name+ " say.");
});

app.get("/repeat/:word/:times", function(req, res){
    var word = req.params.word;
    var times = parseInt(req.params.times);

    for(var i = 1; i<= times; i++){
        res.send(word);   
     }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

Comment: you cant send res.send() in a loop

Comment: you can merge the strings with spaces and send it in `res.send()`

Comment: `res.send()` can only be called once per request because it sends and finalizes the response.  You can call `res.write()` multiple times and then `res.end()` at the end.

Comment: Actually you can!! by returning ,, `return res.send()` and by returning, it will exit from the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as first answer you can do something like.

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:times", function(req, res){
    var word = req.params.word;
    var times = parseInt(req.params.times);
    for(var i = 1; i<= times; i++){
         word = ' ' + word;  
     }
   res.send(word);
});
```

if you want a streaming api the look this documentation `server-send-events(sse)`

Answer (score 2):

No.

Look at [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send):

> Sends the HTTP response

You can't have multiple responses to a single request.

---

Build a single response body in a variable as you loop. Send it once the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using res.send, use res.write then res.end outside the loop, because you can only send responses one time so it doesn't work in a loop.

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:num", function(req, res){
  var number = req.params.num;
  var word = req.params.word;
  var numnum = parseInt(number);
  for(var i = 0; i < numnum ; i++){
    res.write(" " + word + " ");
  }
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: Leaving just code answers is often not helpful, consider giving an explanation of your code. Also be aware this question is two years old

Comment: @R10t-- is correct. You must have to explain what changes you did with a reason. So beginner can understand this code too.

Comment: i'm so sorry, i'll add some explanation now, this is my first answer here, also what's wrong with answering old questions?

Comment: In general, I think answering an old question that has an accepted answer isn't typically helpful.  However, you added an alternative approach (res.write) that had not been mentioned yet so that's good.  The answer would be even better if you explained the trade-offs this brings compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:times", function(req, res) {
    var word = req.params.word;
    var times = parseInt(req.params.times);
    var x = '';
    var y = word + ' ';
    for (var i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
        x += y;
    }
    res.send(x);
});
```

I tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by wrapping the for loop in a function, and then

```js
res.send(functionName(times));
```

Since I am also a beginner, I don´t think it is the best practice, but it worked...

```js
app.get("/repeat/:word/:times", function(req, res){
    var word = req.params.word;
    var times = parseInt(req.params.times);
    var str = ''

    function myFunction(n){
    for(var i = 1; i <= times; i++){
        str += word + ' ';
    }
        return str;
    }
        res.send(myFunction(times));
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

Sending response again on the same request will give you Can't set headers error.

One request can have just one response.